# Iterating over Collection<Object>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have the following `Collection<Player>`

```
    public interface Player {
    String getUsername();

    int getHealth();

    int getArmor();

    Gun getGun();

    boolean isAlive();

    void takeDamage(int points);
}
```

which is implemented by two identical classes

TeamOne and TeamTwo

```
public class TeamOne implements Player {

    private String username;
    private int health;
    private int armor;
    private boolean isAlive;
    private Gun gun;

    protected TeamOne(String username, int health, int armor, Gun gun) {
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setHealth(health);
        this.setArmor(armor);
        this.setGun(gun);
 }
```

then from Collection I create two List teamOne and List teamTwo

```
List<Player> teamOne = players.stream().filter(p instanceof TeamOne).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Player> teamTwo = players.stream().filter(p instanceof TeamTwo).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is there a way to create stream from both list and create the following function as we don't know their size which maybe is not equal

teamOne.member.takeDamage(teamTwo.member.getGun.fire())

I've try to do this one

```
BiConsumer<List<Player>, Player> action = (f, s) -> {

            f.stream().filter(Player::isAlive).forEach(p -> p.takeDamage(s.getGun().fire()));



        };


  while (teamOne.stream().anyMatch(Player::isAlive) && teamTwo.stream().anyMatch(Player::isAlive)) {

teamOne.stream().filter(Player::isAlive).forEach(t -> action.accept(teamTwo, t));
teamTwo.stream().filter(Player::isAlive).forEach(t -> action.accept(teamOne, t));
}
```

but I think my approach is wrong, and in this case I do more iteration

for each member of teamOne/teamTwo I guess I do iterate the whole teamTwo/teamOne.

Comment: Using `TeamOne` and `TeamTwo` classes is probably not a good idea.  Consider having a field instead for which team a player is on.

Comment: I have thought about that, but at the end I still have the same problem, when they need to fight each other

Comment: Yes I want each live member from team 2 to fire to each live member at team 1

Comment: @LouisWasserman’s suggestion doesn’t in itself solve the problem that you are asking about, agree, but it will prevent many other problems. So please take it to heart, for your own sake and for the sake of those reading or maintaining your code after you.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is some task that I've created to learn Java, but I have stuck on this solution, that's why I posted the question here, now I will look into @LouisWasserman suggestion and maybe I will figure it out somehow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are following @[LouisWasserman’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) suggestion of just one player class and a field for the player’s team, building a team becomes:

```
    List<Player> teamOne = players.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTeamNumber() == 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Team two is similar.

I would not use a stream operation for firing. If you want to do that in spite, here’s a way:

```
    teamTwo.stream()
            .filter(Player::isAlive)
            .forEach(p2 -> teamOne.stream()
                    .filter(Player::isAlive)
                    .forEach(p1 -> p1.takeDamage(p2.getGun().fire())));
```

I would prefer nested `for` loops.